# Using eval() as a "kill switch" in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, eval

I have several WordPress plugins. Once, one of my plugins generated a PHP error in the admin panel. This prevented the blog owners from upgrading or deleting my plugin.
I want put PHP commands on a text file on my website, and make the plugin periodically check the page for new commands. Then use eval() to execute the commands.

What are some downsides to this? Other than the plugin will have to make an extra request.

Comment: Maybe some legal ones (this _is_ a backdoor), security (what if someone forges your endpoint with these commands?), maintainability (these commands may change a lot on the base system, which will make the whole system really hard to maintain in case of errors and even breaches).

Comment: I will never, _ever_ use any software that I find to be doing things like this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In general eval = evil. In this case, if you page gets hacked or compromised, this can now be cascaded to all your users of your plugin. I can highly recommend against this kind of actions.

Comment: If the "page gets hacked" it's kind of insignificant if the exploit code ends up in a needed php script or in a designated text script. The `eval()` in OPs question is nothing more but an `include()`.

Comment: Yes, it's but an incude(), but you wouldn't include() php files from any other place then your local file system, would you? Perhaps our opinions are a bit different, but I find it very significant if I include some random eval() code from a place that cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

So, you screwed up the plugin and hencyby the update mechanism. Using a remote url include() is not a good failsafe against this. I would rather advise that you split up the plugin functionality, and the plugin admin backend.

I realize WP might not aid this separation of concerns, but it might be the more advisable approach here. -- Btw, you might get more concrete recommendations or solutions on [Wordpress.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for this topic.